# Nested form not saving the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models. Firstly I have a voter which has many votes. Votes is a join table to link the voter and the entry. But when I try to save the votes they are not saving. My models look like this:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :voter
  attr_accessible :entry, :voter, :voter_id

class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :verification_code, :verified, :votes_attributes, :votes
  has_many :votes, :class_name => "Vote"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votes

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :caption, :email_address, :filename
end
```

I am then my form looks like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :votes do |builder| %>  
    <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :votes, "Vote" %>
    <%= collection_select(:votes, :entry_id, Entry.all, :id, :caption, :prompt => 'Please select an Entry') %>
    </fieldset>     
  <% end %>
```

But the votes are not saving in the database. The response looks like this:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x5f85viIp/KHJKQF7DotaF3MhebARWcaLDKRbcZw/lM=", "voter"=>{"email_address"=>"sadasfd"}, "votes"=>{"entry_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create Voter"}

So whats going wrong?

Comment: We need to see the controller code that processes the form's POST.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
class Voter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :verification_code, :verified, :votes
  has_many :votes, :class_name => "Vote"
  attr_accessible :votes_attributes,
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :votes

Modify vote_params in VotesController

private
def vote_params
      params.require(:vote).permit(:id, :email_address, :verification_code, :verified, votes_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```